# RuntimeError: output with shape [512] doesn't match the broadcast shape [1, 512, 1, 512] while extracting feature vector using pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network

I am not able to resolve this error. This code is taken from https://becominghuman.ai/extract-a-feature-vector-for-any-image-with-pytorch-9717561d1d4c

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
from PIL import Image
pic_one = '/content/drive/My Drive/Video_Recommender/zframe1.jpg'
pic_two = '/content/drive/My Drive/Video_Recommender/zframe2.jpg'
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
layer = model._modules.get('avgpool')
scaler = transforms.Scale((224, 224))
normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
def get_vector(image_name):
    # 1. Load the image with Pillow library
    img = Image.open(image_name)
    # 2. Create a PyTorch Variable with the transformed image
    t_img = Variable(normalize(to_tensor(scaler(img))).unsqueeze(0))
    # 3. Create a vector of zeros that will hold our feature vector
    #    The 'avgpool' layer has an output size of 512
    my_embedding = torch.zeros(512)
    # 4. Define a function that will copy the output of a layer
    def copy_data(m, i, o):
        my_embedding.copy_(o.data)
    # 5. Attach that function to our selected layer
    h = layer.register_forward_hook(copy_data)
    # 6. Run the model on our transformed image
    model(t_img)
    # 7. Detach our copy function from the layer
    h.remove()
    # 8. Return the feature vector
    return my_embedding
pic_one_vector = get_vector(pic_one)
pic_two_vector = get_vector(pic_two)
```

Error:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-ca2d66de2d9c> in <module>()
----> 1 pic_one_vector = get_vector(pic_one)
      2 pic_two_vector = get_vector(pic_two)

5 frames
<ipython-input-40-a45affe9d8f7> in get_vector(image_name)
     13     h = layer.register_forward_hook(copy_data)
     14     # 6. Run the model on our transformed image
---> 15     model(t_img)
     16     # 7. Detach our copy function from the layer
     17     h.remove()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py in forward(self, x)
    218 
    219     def forward(self, x):
--> 220         return self._forward_impl(x)
    221 
    222 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py in _forward_impl(self, x)
    211         x = self.layer4(x)
    212 
--> 213         x = self.avgpool(x)
    214         x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
    215         x = self.fc(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
--> 552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)
    553             if hook_result is not None:
    554                 result = hook_result

<ipython-input-40-a45affe9d8f7> in copy_data(m, i, o)
      9     # 4. Define a function that will copy the output of a layer
     10     def copy_data(m, i, o):
---> 11         my_embedding.copy_(o.data)
     12     # 5. Attach that function to our selected layer
     13     h = layer.register_forward_hook(copy_data)

RuntimeError: output with shape [512] doesn't match the broadcast shape [1, 512, 1, 512]
```

What I am actually trying to do is trying to extract feature vector from images that I want to further use for building a recommendation system. Do inform me if there is any other alternative available.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Thanks @Vlad Rusu for your helpful answers. It worked!!!!

Comment: Thanks @GreasyGoose !!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to reshape the output data after **avgpool**:

```py
def copy_data(m, i, o):
    my_embedding.copy_(o.data.reshape(o.data.size(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may replace the hook function with the following, just so you don't have to deal with adjusting the output shape:

```
# step 3 and 4
my_embedding = None
def my_hook(module_, input_, output_):
    nonlocal my_output
    my_embedding = output_
```

then simply call the following

```
# step 5
h = layer.register_forward_hook(my_hook)
```